# two div horizontally when one div is disable another should take the whole space 100% width in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, plugin

I have two div's horizontally in one div there is Instagram feed plugin and another is the newsletter, now when Instagram feed plugin is disabled then newsletter should come in the whole space in Magento 2.
[image]
as you can see in the image now when Instagram feed is disabled hello should take the whole space

code to set width

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/
 bootstrap.mi 
 n.css">
</head>
 <div>
<div class="row">
<div id="main1" class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid red;box- 
 sizing: border-box;">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
<div id="main2" class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var main1 = document.getElementById('main1');
     var main2 = document.getElementById('main2');

   //main1.style.display = 'none';
   if(main1.style.display == "none")
      main2.className = "col-md-12";

    // if (true) {} else {}
 </script>
```

Comment: put your code in your post

Comment: you can put `max-width`

Comment: in which post??

Comment: in your question you can put also your code so that it will be easy for others to help you

Comment: where to write the code for this width set i have code to set the width but where to write i dont know

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: I see, where do you want your div to be displayed?

Comment: in home page of the webiste

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: ok take ur time

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this, Add your external css in

> app > design > fronted > [vendor] > [theme] > Magento_Theme > layout > default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then in your Magento admin, go to

> **Content > Pages**
>   Look for  **Home Page** page > Select **Edit** (under actions menu), then click on **Content**  then insert your code:

```
<div>
<div class="row">
<div id="main1"  style="display: none; border: 1px solid red;box- 
 sizing: border-box;">

</div>
<div id="main2" class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var x = document.getElementById("main1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
   main2.className = "col-md-12";
  } 
</script>
```

and it should work after following above instructions

Comment: layout will be in view folder or outside in theme??

Comment: as per your requirement you want to add it on home page, You can directly put your code in Admin > Content > Pages > (your Home Page - page) - Edit Page, and click on content then add your code > then save.

Comment: i am asking about defualt.xml file

Comment: you can do directly, outside in theme, in this path app > design > fronted > [vendor] > [theme] > Magento_Theme > layout > default.xml

Comment: okk let me check

Comment: not working output is coming wrong that the div are coming one after another

Comment: you can change code according to your requirement

Comment: basically, I only showed you how and where to put your codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91020/discussion-between-ashish-ramchandani-and-magefms).

Answer (score 0):

```
For that first you have to check Instagram feed plugin is disable or not.
If disable than add directly set col-md-12 or if enable than set col-md-6.
```

```
<?php 
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

    $moduleManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Module\Manager');

    $isEnabledModule=$moduleManager->isEnabled('YourNamespace_YourModule');

    if($isEnabledModule){
        $class="col-md-6";
    }
    else{
        $class="col-md-12";
    }
?>
<div>
<div class="row">
<?php if($isEnabledModule){ ?>
<div id="main1" class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid red;box- 
 sizing: border-box;">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="main2" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" style="border: 1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but where to write that logic

Comment: Please check I write logic.